# How to change colour filenames and join a graphic column in windows file system using python?

Tags: python, filesystems

I need to change the colour of files in windows filesystem and create a new column with a little icon in it.

I need to do this on single files on the same directory.

Filenames different colours and icons are informative for me.

Imagine that for a file I can colour it in red and that mean that it's in elaboration, or newly created or currently used by more than three editors and so on.

Icons are little ones, and have a different means and ought to be in a different column.

The OS is Windows, but in a near future I would use MAC and Linux, but for now let's focus on windows OS.

I know. It's hard. Any help will be wellcome.